# How to create a child div that would wrap around all other child divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this html structure:

```
<div class="a">
    <div class="b"></div>
    <div class="c"></div>
    <div class="d"></div>
</div>
```

How can would I use jquery to add child div to div "a" that would wrap around "b", "c" and "d"?
Basically, the final html I want should look like this:

```
<div class="a">
    <div class="child">
        <div class="b"></div>
        <div class="c"></div>
        <div class="d"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try,

```
$('.a > div').wrapAll($('<div/>',{'class' : 'child'}));
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/2WwwJ/1/)

Comment: Most effective answer by far

Comment: the answer is probably good and i'll test it. But is there a function I could use with just $('.a') selector? The reason for that is that the selector is dynamically created and used for other purposes, too. It would be much cleaner if I could use a function with $(".a") selector

Comment: @user2395238 Yeah you can use like, `$('.a').children('div').wrapAll...`

Comment: Nice. Now, it's a on hover function. So, how would you reverse it?

Comment: @user2395238 It would be good if you ask a new question by targeting that problem, so you would get more attention from experts... :)

Comment: Try,  `$('.a div:not(".child")').unwrap();` for reverting that.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(function() {
   $('.a > div').wrapAll('<div class="child"></div>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use `.wrapInner()`

```
$('.a').wrapInner('<div class="test"></div>')
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2WwwJ/2/)**

or

use `.wrapAll()`:

```
 $('.a div').wrapAll('<div class="child"></div>')
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2WwwJ/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.a').html('<div class="child">'+$('.a').html()+'</div>');
```